# Amazon EC2 - Windows 2012 R2 - Can't RDP to Instance

Tags: remote-desktop, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 micro instance last week and it was working correctly up until now.  I tried to RDP into the machine today and I'm unable to connect.  I rebooted the machine and tried again with no luck.

I checked the system logs on the instance and it's blank.  Under the Amazon System Checks, only 1/2 passed.  The failed check is due to an "instance reachability check failed."

Is this instance dead in the water?  Somewhat concerned here...  I set up the instance just for a test region, but I want to use Windows and EC2 for my production regions... I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: I have similar problem , did u fixed it ?

Comment: The instance actually ended up being corrupted from what Amazon told me.  I destroyed the dead instance and created a new one from scratch.